# Move from tablet to phone

Tags: android

I have developed my app for tablet. Now I need to convert it to run on phones. What changes to I need to make? Are there any particular steps I need to follow? I tried deploying the app as-is on the phone emulator, but stuff appeared to be cut off.

Comment: You have to desgin seperate screens for android phones. For more details on multiple screen supprt read this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: tablets are basically just big phones (maybe minus the actual phone parts). moving tablet->phone will mean adjusting your UI to deal with a MUCH smaller screen.

Comment: I have gone through newsreader example as Nishant is suggesting. And Marc and Nishant, in this  example also, they have not developed different screens. Just took care of one pane and two pane. But my first screen is just simple login page with username and password.That is also cutting from side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've asked a general question, so the best I can do is give you a general answer. The steps and procedures outline [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) should be just what you're looking for. In a very general sense, you're simply going to want to have different layouts for different screens sizes. Android makes this very easy to do with their resource "buckets".

Comment: hey thanks Kurtis, So do I need to keep my layout files also in different folders, like images????

Comment: @BlackDevil Yep, just like you do with images.

Comment: Just t to enquire, this I need to do for values or for layout folder...????? And can u explain a bit about "bucket ", or give alink for details. Thanks